# Angular: Defining models and declaring objects with empty values

Tags: typescript

I am building an angular application and I have defined couple os models in model.ts file. 
I have created an instance of this object in my component. But when I am trying to directly assign a value to a property, it says cannot assign value to undefined.

models.ts

```
export class Staff {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    address: Address;
}

export class Address{
streetName: string;
zipCode: string;
}
```

component.ts

```
  public staff: Staff =  <Staff>{};

staff.address.zipCode = "28657";
```

Here when I try to directly assign a value to the zipcode, it throws an error. 
Is there a way to declare the object with default empty values '' ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Error

When you instantiate a new `Staff` all values default to `null`.
Therefore `staff.address` is `null` and you try to access the `zipCode` property of `null` which leads to the given error.

#### Custom default values: ordinary constructor

You can define your own constructors in which you set your desired default values.
For example in your `Address` class:

```
constructor (zipCode?: string) {
    if (zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
    // process other values
}
```

The constructor is called when you instantiate a new Address. In this example it takes an optional parameter `zipCode` (optional because of the `?`). So you could either instantiate it like this:

```
address: Address = new Address();
```

or like this:

```
address: Address = new Address("04107");
```

#### Constructor with public/private

Typescript gives you a shorthand notation for the above:

```
constructor(private zipCode?: string) {}
```

or
    constructor(private zipCode: string = "04107") {}

By prefixing the constructor arguments with `private` (or `public`) typescript will automatically add these variables to the class.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to see is there a way to create a instance of the class with all the empty values.

Comment: Another way is to directly declare properties of your class in the constructor (see updated answer)

Comment: "Empty" should be defined more clearly. For example should an empty string be `undefined` or ""?

Answer (score 0):

In the compiler section, there is a property called strictPropertyInitialization,

this property forces you to initialize the attributes

to fix this -> set the false property in the compiler options like this :

```
"strictPropertyInitialization": false
```

Comment: Is this in tsconfig.json?

Comment: yes, in the tsconfig.json add this property to compilerOptions

Comment: like that "compilerOptions": { "strictPropertyInitialization": false}